# How to avoid Unity Random.Range function to generate same numbers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have a method to generate a GameObject at a certain (random) angle each time the method is called.
Sometimes it happens that two GameObject are generated by this method at same random angle, overlapping them.

I need to avoid this but I don't know how to do.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public Branch CreateBranch()
{
    GameObject newBranchGo = new GameObject("Branch");
    newBranchGo.transform.position = transform.position;
    newBranchGo.transform.parent = transform;

    newBranchGo.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;

    var angle = tree.GoldenAngle;
    if (tree.NumChildren == 1)
    {
        angle = 0;
        //Debug.Log("Angle: " + angle);
        newBranchGo.transform.Rotate(angle, 0f, 0f, Space.Self);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.8f)
        {
            angle = -angle;
        }

        if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.5f)
        {
            newBranchGo.transform.Rotate(angle, 0f, 0f, Space.Self);
        }
        else
        {
            newBranchGo.transform.Rotate(0f, angle, 0f, Space.Self);
        }
    }

    Branch branch = newBranchGo.AddComponent<Branch>();
    branch.BranchInit(tree, GetComponent<Bud>());

    return branch;
}
```

Comment: I dont see where your randomness is coded, but you can store the last angle somewhere in variable, and before you return branch, you can check if the number generated is the same.

Comment: Here:

else
    {
        if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.8f)
        {
            angle = -angle;
        }

        if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.5f)
        {
            newBranchGo.transform.Rotate(angle, 0f, 0f, Space.Self);
        }
        else
        {
            newBranchGo.transform.Rotate(0f, angle, 0f, Space.Self);
        }
    }

Comment: In your code there are only 2 angles possible(if `tree.NumChildren != 1)`: actual `angle` of parent `GameObject` and `angle * -1` . Is this what you want?

Comment: the `tree.GoldenAngle;`  in `var angle = tree.GoldenAngle;`  is actually an hardcoded value: is set at start, for example `public float GoldenAngle = 30f;`
The method generates the Branch GameObject each time rotated by  random "angle" but sometimes happens that two consecutive method calls generate same random "angle", overlapping two new Branch GameObjects

Comment: `Sometimes it happens` .. well yeah that's a random value so it can indeed happen that you get similar values twice

Comment: Are you creating these branches in a breadth first type of traversal? Please include the code calling `CreateBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method is [rejection-sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). Simply take your random value, do some check, and generate a new value if the check fails. In this case I would assume the check would be if objects overlap or the value is to close to a previous value.

Answer (score -1):

You can change starting seed of random number generator in Unity so every time latest seed generates different random numbers within range Something Like:

```
    Random.InitState(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);
    float NonRepeatedResult = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    if(NonRepeatedResult < 0.8f)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
    ......
```

Here current milliseconds change rapidly every time , changing seed for every random number generation which adds element of uniqueness in consecutive generations.

Comment: it still could generate the same angle.